# Install jenkins plugin from github in dockerfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, plugins

I have a simple Dockerfile where I install Jenkins and some plugins:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.169-alpine

USER root
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache curl docker jq tzdata \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
```

There is now a jenkins plugin with a custom patch I would need to include. There's already a PR open for it but it's been months it was not merged and I can't wait anymore, so I'd like to add a step to install a plugin from a branch of my github repo.

I found out that after the `jenkins-cli.jar` is available (so, not at build time), one can install a plugin in `hpi` format doing:

`java -jar /var/jenkins_home/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar \
  -auth user:password \
  -s http://localhost:8080 install-plugin file://<HPI_PATH>`

but it cannot work at build time.
If not possible in the dockerfile, is there an alternative?

Comment: Can't you just copy the hpi file to the plugin directory at the end. When Jenkins starts it will incorporate it

Comment: I read that the jpi takes precedence before the hpi, in this case it would be ignored, no?

Comment: you could remove the jpi file too. You'll need to check that all the dependencies are correct. Alternatively, if there is an experimental build, you can use it by using `experimental` rather than `latest` https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/install-plugins.sh#L73

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging PR, I found the solution here https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/pull/799

This is not an install from github but it will work out

So you just need to add at the end of your dockerfile (being root and not jenkins user):

```
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh plugin-name:plugin-version:hpi-url
```

Answer (score 0):

First build the plugin.hpi locally and then Use copy or Add in Dockerfile to add plugin into jenkins docker images in  build step.

**example** 
Add https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/sonar/2.8.1/sonar.hpi /var/jenkins_home/plugins/

Or

**Install sonar plugin using local build hpi file.**

Copy sonar.hpi  /var/jenkins_home/plugins/

Comment: I just tried, it basically ignores it and installs the jpi